# Парсинг большого XML-файла

Tags: python, парсер

При парсинге большого XML-документа столкнулся с ошибкой MemoryError. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Вернее проблема-то понятно, что с памятью, но как решить? Читал про потоковые парсеры sax: сложно, нелегко. Ошибку выдает в 30-ой строке.

```
from lxml import etree
import glob

def getTextFromSingleElement(xmlString, xpath):
  root = etree.XML(xmlString)
  xpathProvider = etree.XPath(xpath)
  elements = xpathProvider(root)
  if (len(elements) == 0):
    print('WARNING: ' + getPatentFile(xmlString) + ' Has no targetElement' + '\n')
    return ''
  if (len(elements) > 1):
    print('WARNING: ' + getPatentFile(xmlString) + ' Two elements' + '\n')
    return ''
  return elements[0].text

def getPatentFile(xmlString):
  root = etree.XML(xmlString)
  xpathProvider = etree.XPath('/us-patent-application')
  elements = xpathProvider(root)
  if (len(elements) == 0):
    return 'NO FILE INFO!'
  return elements[0].attrib['file']

DATA_PATH = 'D:\patent\ipa050120'
TARGET_XPATH = '/us-patent-application/us-bibliographic-data-application/classification-ipc/main-classification'
SPLITTER = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'

for filename in glob.iglob(DATA_PATH + '/**/*.xml', recursive=True):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
     rawData = f.read()

  splittedData = rawData.split(SPLITTER)[1:]

  result = []
  for partitialXml in splittedData:
    element = getTextFromSingleElement(partitialXml, TARGET_XPATH)
    if (element.startswith('A23B') or element.startswith('G06Q')):
      result.append(partitialXml)
  with open('result.txt', 'a') as resultFile:
    resultFile.write('\n'.join(map(lambda xml: SPLITTER + xml, result)))
```

Comment: используйте `for line in f:`, потом из строк собираете осмысленные части xml и их парсите

Comment: В общем-то `sax` как раз и позволяет за счет увеличения сложности выиграть и память, и скорость.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693535/what-is-a-good-xml-stream-parser-for-python

Comment: @EugeneDennis - файл может состоять из одной-единственной (огромной) строки. Так что опять будет полностью грузиться в память. Наоборот, один элемент xml может быть разбить на несколько строк. Собрать его будет сложно.